# Node.js (Express.js) using Redis Store - Disable session TTL reset with every request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, redis, express-session

I want to disable session TTL reset with every request to the server. **Keeping** the initial session TTL whether the user is active or inactive.

My final goal, is to let the user extend the session manually by clicking "extend" button on dedicated popup in my App and also limit the number of session extends.

**This is my current configuration**:

```
app.use(
  session({
    genid: req => req.sessionUuid,
    store: new RedisStore(
      {
        client: redisClient,
        ttl: 3600
      }),
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    proxy: app.get('env') !== 'development' && needProxy()
  })
);
```

From `Express.js` [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html) I understand this is not the default behaviour. Only, if you use the `rolling` parameter I should expect TTL reset behaviour.

I should mention I'm not using `Cookie` in my app, only sever session.